# My site migration from 2007 to 2010 issue

Tags: migration

We are migrating My Site from 2007 to 2010 using database attach method. By default on 2007 my site page there is a web part called “My Sharepoint Site” that user have added details to. 
When we migrate this to SharePoint 2010, this web part is not available by default. **If we add this web part from gallery it adds a new web part and data that user have modified is not reflected.**

Any help or suggestion will be very helpful.